# How does Linux allocate memory for its physical allocator?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel

I was recently delving into the details of Linux's memory management as I want to implement something similar for my own toy kernel, so I was hoping if someone who's familiar with the details could help me understand one thing. Apparently the physical memory manager is a buddy algorithm, which is further specialised to return blocks of pages of a particular order (0 to 9, with 0 being just a single page). For each order the blocks are stored as a linked list. Say if a block of order 5 is requested but is not found on the list of order 5 blocks, the algorithm searches for a block in order 6, splits it into two, gives the requested half and moves the other half an order lower (as it is half in size). 
What I don't get is how the kernel stores these structures, or how it allocates space for them. Since for order 0 pages you would need 1M entries (each is a 4KiB page), does it mean that the kernel allocates 1MiB * sizeof(struct page)? What about the blocks of order 1 and above? Does the kernel reuse allocated blocks by marking them as a higher order, and when it needs to split it in two just return the block and get one that is unused?

Comment: Some useful links: Buddy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation, Mel Gorman's book "Understanding the Linux Virtual Memory Manager" - chapter 2 Describing Physical Memory https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand005.html and Mauerer's "Professional Linux Kernel Architecture" book, section 3.5 "Management of physical memory"

Comment: I have done my research with these links but they don't answer my question as they are just theory, not the practical implementation. I would like to know how Linux sets up the memory structures, where it places them in physical memory, how it reserves memory for these blocks that represent pages... Because in order to split a block into two it must have two new blocks to represent them (or just one new if the split block can be reused). This is something that all this theory doesn't explain -- how to practically do it! There isn't a straightforward init() func within the kernel source code...

Comment: Check  "Professional Linux Kernel Architecture", all code is described in it (3.5, 3.5.3 - page 209). I will post answer soon.

Comment: Say if the implementation were something simple like storing a bitmap with each bit representing a node, you could reserve 2M - 1 bits, which is ~256KiB of memory. Children nodes would be found as parent*2 and parent*2 + 1, and children's parent is found as child/2. Finding a buddy could be as simple as determining if the current node bit is odd or even, and adding or subtracting 1 to find the buddy. The map could be stored in physical range 0x00100000 to 0x00140000! But Linux doesn't do this simple and nodes are structs, not bits! I'm trying to understand how they are manipulated in memory...

Comment: @osgx Alright, will do!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What I don't get is how the kernel stores these structures, or how it allocates space for them. Since for order 0 pages you would need 1M entries (each is a 4KiB page), does it mean that the kernel allocates 1MiB * sizeof(struct page)?

Initialization of zones is done by calling [`paging_init()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/mm/init_32.c?v=3.16#L690) (arch/x86/mm/init_32.c; some descriptions - https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand005.html 2.3 Zone Initialisation and http://repo.hackerzvoice.net/depot_madchat/ebooks/Mem_virtuelle/linux-mm/vminit.html Initializing the Kernel Page Tables) from [`setup_arch()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/setup.c?v=3.16#L851) via ([`native_pagetable_init()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/mm/init_32.c?v=3.16#L452) and indirect call `1166         x86_init.paging.pagetable_init();`):

```
690 /*
691  * paging_init() sets up the page tables - note that the first 8MB are
692  * already mapped by head.S.
...*/
697 void __init paging_init(void)
698 {
699         pagetable_init();
...
711         zone_sizes_init();
712 }
```

`pagetable_init()` creates kernel page tables in `swapper_pg_dir` array of 1024 `pgd_t`s.

[`zone_sizes_init()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/mm/init.c?v=3.16#L663) actually defines zones of physical memory and calls [`free_area_init_nodes()` to initialize them](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/page_alloc.c?v=3.16#L5293) with actual work done (for each NUMA node `for_each_online_node(nid) {...}`) in [`free_area_init_node()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/page_alloc.c?v=3.16#L4958) which calls three functions:

- `calculate_node_totalpages()` prints page counts for every node in dmesg
- [`alloc_node_mem_map()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/page_alloc.c?v=3.16#L4916) does actual job of allocating `struct page` for every physical page in this node; memory for them is allocated by bootmem allocator [doc1](http://repo.hackerzvoice.net/depot_madchat/ebooks/Mem_virtuelle/linux-mm/bootmem.html) [doc2](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand008.html) (you can see its debug with `bootmem_debug=1` kernel boot option):

`4936                 size =  (end - start) * sizeof(struct page);`

`4937                 map = alloc_remap(pgdat->node_id, size);`

`if (!map)      map = memblock_virt_alloc_node_nopanic(size, pgdat->node_id);`

- [`free_area_init_core()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/page_alloc.c?v=3.16#L4809) (with filling of bitmaps in [`struct zone`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/mmzone.h?v=3.16#L326)). Functionality of `free_area_init_core` described for older kernels in http://repo.hackerzvoice.net/depot_madchat/ebooks/Mem_virtuelle/linux-mm/zonealloc.html#INITIALIZE as:

> `free_area_init_core()` The memory map is built, and the freelists and buddy bitmaps initialized, in free_area_init_core().

Free lists of orders in each zone are initialized and orders are marked as having no any free page: `free_area_init_core()` -> [`init_currently_empty_zone()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/page_alloc.c?v=3.16#L4374) -> [`zone_init_free_lists`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/page_alloc.c?v=3.16#L4147):

```
4147 static void __meminit zone_init_free_lists(struct zone *zone)
4148 {
4149         unsigned int order, t;
4150         for_each_migratetype_order(order, t) {
4151                 INIT_LIST_HEAD(&zone->free_area[order].free_list[t]);
4152                 zone->free_area[order].nr_free = 0;
4153         }
4154 }
```

PS: There **is** init() in kernel, it is called [`start_kernel()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/main.c?v=3.16#L501), and LXR (Linux cross-reference) will help you to navigate between functions (I posted links to lxr.free-electrons.com, but there are several online LXRs):

```
501 asmlinkage __visible void __init start_kernel(void)
...
528         boot_cpu_init();
529         page_address_init();
530         pr_notice("%s", linux_banner);
531         setup_arch(&command_line);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's perfect! It took me some time to follow the logic of all the different components but now I have a clearer picture. Now I just need to figure out how the bitmap and nodes are manipulated because it doesn't seem clear to me... If a node is halved and one half is moved to a lower order list, is it appended or somehow put in the middle of the freelist? When it's time to coalesce two nodes, how is the buddy found?

Comment: This is pretty late, but what I see from the source code is that `struct page` has a pointer back to the associated free list node, thus achieving constant time removal from least. See https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.3/C/ident/del_page_from_free_list `list_del(&page->lru);`